# Get function parameter from data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a parameter of a function from a data attribute, like there is a function which accept parameters:

```
$(element).transition({
    x:'100%',
    opacity: '0.5'
});
```

and I wan to get `transition` parameters from a data attribute, like:

```
<div class="have-data" data-transition="x:'100%',opacity: '0.5'">
    ....
</div>
```

Now i want to get parameters from data attribute and set it `.transition()` parameter to like:

`.transition($('.have-data').data('transition'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following attribute value

```
<div class="have-data" data-transition='{"x":"100%","opacity": "0.5"}'>
    ....
</div>
```

And use

```
.transition($('.have-data').data('transition'))
```

jQuery is smart and automagically converts your data from JSON to plain JS object. But note, you must use " instead of ' for quoting field names of your config-object

Comment: Please note: I am creating my data attributes using attr,

Comment: I am having problem, As I am creating data attribute using attr I cant use `'`, `$(elem).attr('data-transition', input.value)` I am using attr cause I am saving HTML to database. Any suggestion please

Comment: I will use this in data attribute: `x:100%|opacity:0.5` and later I will use `.replace()`. Done

Comment: @user007 why are you using `attr()` to create data attributes? Use `data()` as that's what it was intended for.

Comment: Already told, if I create data using `data()` then it will not visible in DOM, so if you save HTML you will not get data

Comment: Why just not use .attr('data-transition', JSON.stringify({ x: "100%", opacity: 0.5 }))